# MATLAB: Find row index of elements in a matrix <0.001, excluding certain rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, cobra

I am using the Cobra Toolbox in MATLAB to perform a double gene knockout study and output for growth ratios is a 100 by 100 matrix called grRatioDble. I need to find the row and column index for elements of this matrix which are <0.001, excluding the rows which were essential on single gene knockout. I have a one-column matrix of the row indexes that I want to exclude. Is there an easy way to do this?

(NB: I cannot just remove the unwanted rows from the matrix as then row, column index changes for the remaining cells)

Comment: This resource is more about programming than science. If you need some help with the code provide it.

Comment: My question is not really about the science, I just want to know how to extract the row and column indexes of those elements from a Matlab matrix.

Comment: have you tried google?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html

Comment: Actually yes, for several hours now. I could not find the answer I wanted, hence asking here... I didn't find the answer on that link either.

Comment: Basically you are asking "How can I find the indexes of elements that are less than a value?" And this is described in the page I provided. If there is a problem with your specific task then provide the code you've tried and we'll try to figure out how to fix it

Comment: That is the first part of my question, yes, but doesn't include the second part. My question is "How can I find the indexes of elements that are less than a value, EXCLUDING rows and columns eg. 2,7,12,15". 

I agree that the answer to the first part of the question is on the page you linked, but I cannot find out how to exclude certain rows from the query anywhere.

Comment: That is a fourth use of *"Cobra"* (the 3 others are described in [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cobra/info)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code should do the work:

1. Get all row/col indexes where `grRatioDble<0.001`:

   ```
   [row,col] = find(grRatioDble<0.001);
   ```
2. Exclude unwanted rows (say the vector containing unwanted rows is `rows2exclude`):

   ```
   row = row(~ismember(row, rows2exclude));
   col = col(~ismember(row, rows2exclude));
   ```